# Query to retrieve status of the machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Sometimes a server where an instance of SQL Server is running needs a restart. This occurs typically when the memory is fully used and rebooting somehow drastically solves the issue. The reason of full memory can be difficult to pinpoint (may be an old service who is running with poor garbage collection or other similar issues, or simply windows OS builtin problems, ...).

When the server is in such instable state a client server application runs into troubles because simple queries fail because SQL Server is not able to handle even simple queries and error messages are returned.

What I'd like to achieve is, just after connection is estabilished, ask the server "do you feel good?".

Is there a way to perform this in T-SQL?

Somehow my desired logic is:

1. connect
2. ask the server "do you feel good" ("`EXEC sp_doyoufeelgood`")

   - if it feels good continue
   - else close the application and inform the user "the server is encountering some problems, please contact your sysadmin"

Is there a reliable way to check for a SQL Server instance status?

Comment: "The reason of full memory can be difficult to pinpoint" Have you opened task manager yet and identified the process that is using all the memory? SQL Server should generally not have anything else installed on it. You might find SQL is taking all the memory meaning... you need more memory. There are a multitude of counters you can check on your server. If you are certain it's running out of memory then you can use perfmon to watch the memory used counter. But you're better off identifying what the issue is than just rebooting it when you have problems

Comment: Check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) on how to tweak memory settings for SQL Server. Normally this is done dynamically but in some server setups this can lead to problems with other processes. Maybe you could set a lower bound to allow SQL Server to perform without memory problems?

Comment: In the world of ideas all sql server instances are installed on dedicated machines (ideally in private or public cloud), but in real life many times i face "the server", a single (may be old) server who hosts everything, that "beast" sometimes has problems and if the client application can know that the server is in troubles by running a query it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this one could be interesting: 
sp_Blitz® http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/

Comment: Thanks for the usefuel link! I downlaoded the script and immediately took advantage from it. It is a good answer but i do not accept it as my solution since sp_Blitz tells me how to better tune my sql server (so it is an admin tool), somehow it nails the problem, but i'd like to have a sp_systemcheck sp that returns a simple value (0 = all ok, 1 = suffering, 2 = needs a reboot). I know it is empyrical, but in real life it helps